# Formatting old Query to LINQ statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, c#-4.0

The following query is something i inherited from an old app that adds 2 attributes to an excel stored in the database.

```
SELECT 
   row_number() over(order by id) as num
   , [id] as mailsort
   , 0 as pages
   , [xmlRecord].query('/sst-statement/*') 
FROM  dbo.RPA200_preproc AS [sst-statement] 
WHERE rpatype = 201 
ORDER BY id for xml auto
```

returns an XML starting with

```
<sst-statement num="1" mailsort="32" pages="0">
```

now, the SQL would need to be translated to a LINQ statement. Is that possible similar to this query or would it be better to retrieve the XML from database and then change the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
row_number() over(order by id) as num,
[id] as mailsort,
0 as pages,
[xmlRecord].query('/sst-statement/*')
FROM  dbo.RPA200_preproc as [sst-statement]
where rpatype = 201
order by id for xml auto
```

turned into

```
int i=0;
var Query =
FROM I in dbo.RPA200_preproc
WHERE rpatype = 201
order by id
SELECT I.id;
foreach(var Item in Query)
{
    new XElement("sst-statement", new XAttribute("num", i), new XAttribute("mailsort" = Item), new XAttribute("Pages",(int)0));
    i++;
}
```

I think :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. i can't test it at the moment, due to other work having passed this. i will test it as soon as i can.